# Null pointer when getting intent extra

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, extra

Some times when running my app I get a null pointer when retrieving a value bundled with an intent

setting it in one class

```
private void start(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Tabs.class);
    i.putExtra("helper", checked);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

checked is a boolean value and is never null

getting it in the other class

```
private void getExtra(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    mExtra = extras.getBoolean("helper");
}
```

any ideas as to why it would be null sometimes?

Comment: Does this happens when you navigate back to this activity after hitting "Back" button on other activity or via Task Manager?

Comment: hitting the back button at this point in the application would just exit the app since i have the previous activity set as no history

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getBooleanExtra()` to get the value from intent

### Sample Code

```
boolean mExtra = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("helper", false);
```

Comment: it will not return null, he/she was getting null. also if the data for the key "helper" is present it will return true. if no data is present with the key "helper" it will return false

Comment: why wouldn't the key be there? I have a feeling that may be the actual problem where the key is not there sometimes